# How does one bind style values in code-behind?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

My application generates a dynamic number of styles in code-behind. I'd like to bind a specific property of those styles to a dependency property. It's possible in XAML, but I found no way to do it in code-behind. Since Setter is no FrameworkElement, it does not provide a SetBinding() method. And since Setter.Value is no dependency property BindingOperations.SetBinding() won't work either.

How does

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
</Style>
```

look in code-behind?

Comment: Silverlight has been supporting the setting of a style multiple times/dynamically since version 3: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/08/silverlight-3-s-new-style-enhancements.aspx

Comment: That `Style` can be re-assigned is not in question here.  Its whether in this case the binding does what seems to be implied.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Why wouldn't it, if it works in Xaml? The question was about turning the working Xaml into C#

Comment: @Erno: I dunno why I thought that didn't work in SL4, I must have been having a bit of a brain fade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
this.DataContext = new Thing { FontSize = 5.5 };

Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
style.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, new Binding("FontSize")));

textBlock1.Style = style;
```

Comment: What version of Silverlight did you test this in?  I don't think this works in SL4.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Silverlight 4 target but SL 5 plugin

Comment: Silverlight has been supporting the setting of a style multiple times/dynamically since version 3: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/08/silverlight-3-s-new-style-enhancements.aspx

Comment: +1 Yes this does do what is expected in Silverlight 4 as well.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't set the DataContext. After that didn't work I was looking for something like Style.SetBinding().